# Run Build and Watch in Parallel with Nx

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a monorepo setup like:

```
└── monorepo/
    ├── package.json
    ├── apps/
    │   └── website/
    │       └── package.json
    └── packages/
        └── elements/
            └── package.json
```

From the monorepo root I'd like to be able to have a command that runs a build watch on the elements package and then concurrently serves up website.

I see that Nx has a [run-many](https://nx.dev/packages/nx/documents/run-many) command, but that seems more useful if you trying to run a similar command across multiple packages, for example running `test` on multiple packages at the same time. My situation is different, I want to run build in one and serve in the other.

I'm guessing I'm missing something with the configuration files.